# Bayesian Predictive Posterior Distribution for Batch Defect Probability

Tags: bayesian

For a research project, I need to assess the probability that a new batch is defective. I want to use a predictive posterior distribution for this purpose, as it incorporates uncertainty. A beta-binomial distribution seems most appropriate to me, given that I only have defect rates from previous batches. Can someone assist me in setting up a formula? I am not very familiar with Bayesian analysis.

The inspection process is as follows, a random sample is taken from a batch and compared with the Acceptable Quality Level (AQL) standard, which is set at 0.15. To illustrate, I've provided data on some recent batch inspections for a specific product:

- Batch 1: Q tested: 6 units Defective: 3 units Batch rejected,
- Batch 2: Q tested: 6 units Defective: 0 units Batch accepted,
- Batch 3: Q:12 units Defective: 7 units Batch rejected,
- Batch 4: Q:18 units Defective: 5 units Batch rejected,
- Batch 5: Q:13 units Defective: 5 units Batch rejected,
- Batch 6: Q:18 units Defective: 0 units Batch Accepted,
- Batch 7: Q:4 units Defective: 0 units Batch Accepted,
- Batch 8: Q:5 units Defective: 1 units Batch rejected,
- Batch 9: Q:10 units Defective: 0 units Batch Accepted,
- Batch 10: Q:11 units Defective: 0 units Batch Accepted,
- Batch 11: Q:4 units Defective: 1 units Batch rejected,
- Batch 12: Q:21 units Defective: 0 units Batch Accepted,
- Batch 13: Q:7 units Defective: 3 units Batch rejected,
- Batch 14: Q: 38 units Defective: 7 units Batch rejected,
- Batch 15: Q:13 units Defective: 0 units Batch Accepted,

The goal is to rank batches for inspection based on the estimated probability.

Comment: (1) Bayesian methods are not the only ones to include uncertainty in predictions. (2) If all you have is previous batches which were rejected or not, you could go with a straightforward beta, which is a very beginner-friendly prior distribution for Bayesian analysis, because it is conjugate to itself. If, [for instance, you had 8 accepted and 7 rejected batches](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/630653/1352), this would give you a B(8,7) prior probability for future batches to be accepted, and you can easily update this. ...

Comment: ... Since, judging from your previous posts, you know more than how many batches were accepted/rejected, namely how many units were tested and accepted/rejected in each batch, you might be able to get a little more fancy in your analysis. If this is the case, then I would very much recommend you edit this additional information into your post.

Comment: (3) If [you still don't have any features that distinguish batches](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/630653/1352), then the predictive distribution will still be the same for *every* batch, and you will not be able to achieve your goal of ranking products (batches?) for inspection. I suspect this is more a question of getting more data, and understanding the process better, than of trying more complex modeling.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, i have updated the question

Comment: @StephanKolassa, I prefer your approach that you mentioned in answer 2. So, the prior probability is a beta distribution. Is the likelihood function then a bernoulli?

Comment: Yes, exactly. [Here is something a quick Google search turned up.](https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2020/08/19/bernoulli-beta/)